# Echo object member of object member

Tags: php, arrays, object

What I'm trying to do here is to echo out the values within the array e.g NAME

So what I can do so far is to echo out the value at top level e.g

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
echo $value->customerSessionId;
```

gives me the correct output: 0ABAAAD2-6922-6914-B822-E2C2A4906CC5

But I want to echo out from the Array under HotelSummary - How do I do that?

The structure is as follows:

```
stdClass Object
(
[HotelListResponse] => stdClass Object
    (
        [customerSessionId] => 0ABAAAD2-6922-6914-B822-E2C2A4906CC5
        [numberOfRoomsRequested] => 1
        [moreResultsAvailable] => 1
        [cacheKey] => -16869226:14b82e2c2a4:-6cc3
        [cacheLocation] => 10.186.170.210:7300
        [cachedSupplierResponse] => stdClass Object
            (
                [@supplierCacheTolerance] => MED_ENHANCED
                [@cachedTime] => 0
                [@cacheEntryMissNum] => 88
                [@cacheRetrievalTime] => 1
                [@supplierRequestNum] => 88
                [@supplierResponseNum] => 20
                [@supplierResponseTime] => 162
                [@candidatePreptime] => 40
                [@otherOverheadTime] => 9
                [@tpidUsed] => 5100
                [@matchedCurrency] => true
                [@extrapolatedLocale] => true
            )

        [HotelList] => stdClass Object
            (
                [@size] => 20
                [@activePropertyCount] => 88
                [HotelSummary] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [@order] => 0
                                [@ubsScore] => 321327565
                                [hotelId] => 168016
                                [name] => First Hotel Mayfair
                                [address1] => Helgolandsgade 3
                                [city] => Copenhagen
                                [postalCode] => 1653
                                [countryCode] => DK
                                [airportCode] => CPH
                                [supplierType] => E
                                [propertyCategory] => 1
```

Comment: You can use `echo $value->HotelList->HotelSummary[0]['hotelId'];` to print the elements of the HotelSummary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

I changed the `json_decode` to `true` so I got arrays.

then I echo:

```
echo $value['HotelList']['HotelSummary'][0][name];
```